# Is it possible to create sdk/library with views for android and ios in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, sdk, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can we create sdk or library in xamarin for android and IOS which. And the library or sdk should also contain some UI (views). Is it possible that library or sdk can contain views that we can use with some other projects of xamarin?

Comment: You may refer to this third party component: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Adapt.Presentation/, its code is open-source on github.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can custom Controls with Bindable Properties in Xamarin.Forms then package it in a nuget package.

For example: you can create a `ContentView` in another folder called **MyCustomControl** like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BindablePropertyDemo.Custom.MyCustomControl">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" 
          Padding="10,40,10,10"
          HeightRequest="160"
          VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="image"
               HeightRequest="100" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label x:Name="title"
               Text="BASKETBALL"
               Grid.Row="1" 
               FontSize="20"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               TextColor="White"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

And then you can call this control from any page like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindablePropertyDemo"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:BindablePropertyDemo.Custom"
             x:Class="BindablePropertyDemo.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#33334c">
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="#ff4284" Padding="10">
                    <Image Source="hamburger.png"/>
                </Grid>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                   Text="Home" 
                   TextColor="#ff4284" 
                   FontSize="20"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Row="1"><
                <!-- SEE HERE!! -->
                <custom:MyCustomControl BackgroundColor="#76dab2" 
                                    TitleText="BASKETBALL" 
                                    Image="basketball.png"/>

                <custom:MyCustomControl BackgroundColor="#7c57e4" 
                                    TitleText="FOOTBALL" 
                                    Image="football.png"/>

                <custom:MyCustomControl BackgroundColor="#f1b136" 
                                    TitleText="GRIDIRON" 
                                    Image="gridiron.png"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

And you will have a result like this:

[image]

I have taken this example of this [tutorial](https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/), you can continue to have more information.

You can find their source code here: https://github.com/mindofai/BindablePropertyDemo